# Ansible ssh connection to remote machine fails with the following error, how do we tweek it to work

Tags: networking, ssh, ansible

when Ansible playbook tries to connect to the (Tomcat server) VM machine which is in the same subnet, it gives the following error:

**Step1:** ssh command the one which ansible playbook uses:

```
ssh -C -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s \
-o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey\
-o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=ec2-user -o ConnectTimeout=10\
-o ControlPath=/var/lib/jenkins/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r -tt 172.31.1.128 '( umask 22 && mkdir -p "$( echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1528657894.57-17447076442650 )" && echo "$( echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1528657894.57-17447076442650 )" )'
```

Output of the SSH command with failure message:

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug1: Control socket "/var/lib/jenkins/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-172.31.1.128-22-ec2-user" does not exist
debug2: resolving "172.31.1.128" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 172.31.1.128 [172.31.1.128] port 22.
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 3 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: timeout: 10000 ms remain after connect
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/server1.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/server1.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 172.31.1.128:22 as 'ec2-user'
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none
debug2: compression stoc: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: zlib@openssh.com
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: zlib@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:4/kIIUmDqoKA1xgTfdHsCGgIWIbWUQf+0BAEBMe0cJM
Warning: Permanently added '172.31.1.128' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/server1.pem ((nil))
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug3: preferred publickey
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred:
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/server1.pem
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:tbkErO+dWUV5xSGkdiFYf3Q9P2ZEgBHUr/dCUZMyANM
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Enabling compression at level 6.
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 172.31.1.128 ([172.31.1.128]:22).
debug1: setting up multiplex master socket
debug3: muxserver_listen: temporary control path /var/lib/jenkins/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-172.31.1.128-22-ec2-user.7se8dQdicjV8JSGk
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 4 is O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 4 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [/var/lib/jenkins/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-172.31.1.128-22-ec2-user]
debug3: muxserver_listen: mux listener channel 0 fd 4
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x08
debug1: control_persist_detach: backgrounding master process
debug2: control_persist_detach: background process is 3613
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: forking to background
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: id
debug2: set_control_persist_exit_time: schedule exit in 60 seconds
debug1: multiplexing control connection
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 5 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 1: new [mux-control]
debug3: channel_post_mux_listener: new mux channel 1 fd 5
debug3: mux_master_read_cb: channel 1: hello sent
debug2: set_control_persist_exit_time: cancel scheduled exit
debug3: mux_master_read_cb: channel 1 packet type 0x00000001 len 4
debug2: process_mux_master_hello: channel 1 slave version 4
debug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4
debug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote
debug3: mux_client_request_session: entering
debug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering
debug3: mux_master_read_cb: channel 1 packet type 0x10000004 len 4
debug2: process_mux_alive_check: channel 1: alive check
debug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 3615
debug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent
debug3: mux_master_read_cb: channel 1 packet type 0x10000002 len 237
debug2: process_mux_new_session: channel 1: request tty 1, X 0, agent 0, subsys 0, term "xterm", cmd "( umask 22 && mkdir -p "$( echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1528657894.57-17447076442650 )" && echo "$( echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1528657894.57-17447076442650 )" )", env 1
debug3: process_mux_new_session: got fds stdin 6, stdout 7, stderr 8
debug1: channel 2: new [client-session]
debug2: process_mux_new_session: channel_new: 2 linked to control channel 1
debug2: channel 2: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: callback start
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 2
debug2: channel 2: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 2: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug1: Sending command: ( umask 22 && mkdir -p "$( echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1528657894.57-17447076442650 )" && echo "$( echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1528657894.57-17447076442650 )" )
debug2: channel 2: request exec confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: mux_session_confirm: sending success reply
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 2: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 2
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 2
debug2: channel 2: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 2
debug2: exec request accepted on channel 2
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 2 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug3: mux_exit_message: channel 2: exit message, exitval 0
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 2 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 2: rcvd eow
debug2: channel 2: close_read
debug2: channel 2: input open -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 2: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 2: output open -> drain
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 2: rcvd close
debug3: channel 2: will not send data after close
/home/ec2-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1528657894.57-17447076442650
debug3: channel 2: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 2: obuf empty
debug2: channel 2: close_write
debug2: channel 2: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 2: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug2: channel 2: is dead
debug2: channel 2: gc: notify user
debug3: mux_master_session_cleanup_cb: entering for channel 2
debug2: channel 1: rcvd close
debug2: channel 1: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 1: close_read
debug2: channel 1: input open -> closed
debug2: channel 2: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 2: is dead
debug2: channel 2: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 2: free: client-session, nchannels 3
debug3: channel 2: status: The following connections are open:
  #2 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cc -1)

debug2: channel 1: obuf empty
debug2: channel 1: close_write
debug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe
debug2: Received exit status from master 0
Shared connection to 172.31.1.128 closed.
root@ip-172-31-8-75:~/.ssh# debug2: channel 1: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 1: is dead (local)
debug2: channel 1: gc: notify user
debug3: mux_master_control_cleanup_cb: entering for channel 1
debug2: channel 1: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 1: is dead (local)
debug2: channel 1: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 1: free: mux-control, nchannels 2
debug3: channel 1: status: The following connections are open:

debug2: set_control_persist_exit_time: schedule exit in 60 seconds
debug1: ControlPersist timeout expired
debug3: send packet: type 1
debug1: channel 0: free: /var/lib/jenkins/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-172.31.1.128-22-ec2-user, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:

debug3: fd 0 is not O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 1 is not O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 2572, received 2480 bytes, in 60.3 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 42.7, received 41.1
debug1: Exit status -1
debug1: compress outgoing: raw data 594, compressed 370, factor 0.62
debug1: compress incoming: raw data 370, compressed 594, factor 1.61
```

Could some one please help me in troubleshooting this and fixing the ssh to work.

Keys to connect to 172.31.1.128 are present in a file called server1.pem and is located at  ~/.ssh/server1.pem location which is given to ansible.cfg with reference to 
https://github.com/maheshkharwadkar/devops/tree/master/ansible/e2eproject

**Step2:** Although, a simple command:

```
ssh ec2-user@172.31.1.128
```

works super cool.

However it fails through the playbook execution when above ssh command in step 1 is ran.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the exact answer you are looking for, but seeing  a file transfer happenning, tells me Ansible is trying to install some of it's packages for remote adminstration, and it's not a connectivity issue.

Maybe try without the ControlPath options to see if the SSH multiplexing is the culprit or ensure that a single SSH connection is happening at the time?

I had a similar problem with Ansible, but my problem was that a python library was not available on my host, to allow Ansible remote administration. I ended up specifying to not gather facts on my playbook, then performing commands via the raw module.

```
- hosts: my_hosts
  remote_user: admin
  vars_files:
  - my_var_file.yml
  vars:
    ansible_ssh_private_key_file: ~/.ssh/mykey.pub
  gather_facts: no
```